# React website created using Create-react-app deployed on Apache Tomcat giving blank screen

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, react-router, react-redux, create-react-app

Created a react app using create-react-app. Everything works fine on local system but getting issues when deploying it on Apache tomcat. Below are the steps i followed for deployment:

1. Added **"homepage":"https://websiteName.com/react_web"** in package.json.
2. Create .htaccess file in public folder of project and added below code

   Options -MultiViews
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
3. Run "npm run build" to create build files.
4. Copied the content of build file into 'react_web' folder in Apache tomcat.

There are no errors in console of browser.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="//websiteName.com/react_web/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//websiteName.com/react_web/favicon.ico"><title>React App</title><link href="//websiteName.com/react_web/static/css/main.d17afb7e.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//websiteName.com/react_web/static/js/main.b302e125.js"></script></body></html>
```

Below are few pics from browser console.

[image]

I am using BrowserRouter for routing. Do i have to change something there.

Also i see all the project files being loaded properly in console.

Any suggestion or direction will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Was missing below part.

Note: If you are using `react-router@^4`, you can root `<Link>s` using the `basename` prop on any `<Router>`.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/>
// renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths